# How to animate a view being removed from a ViewPager?

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager in which I programmatically remove a view and set it to a new page, a little bit like this:

```
private static class ProfilesPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
        private ArrayList<SherlockFragment> mViews = new ArrayList<SherlockFragment>();
        ...
}  

mProfilesPagerAdapter.mViews.remove(position);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mProfilesPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(newPos);
```

Is there a way I could put an animation on the view that is being removed?

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to copy the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class and `setCustomAnimations` after `beginTransaction` method:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mCurTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }
    ...
}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mCurTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    } 

    ...
}
```

Source of [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java)